# Capture google plus https traffic using wireshark?

Tags: ssl, https, wireshark, web-traffic, network-traffic

I am using Linux/Wireshark to capture http traffic and it's working great. Now i want to capture some AJAX calls from https://plus.google.com, but in this case I am not able to see any simple data.

I saw some articles and confused, Can someone explain, what steps should I follow to get the desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to decrypt HTTPS traffic, you need the server private key. As you have no way of getting Google's private key for plus.google.com, there is no way to decrypt the captured traffic.

In addition to having the private key, the TLS transaction must not be using Perfect Forward Secrecy.

Comment: Is there no way to make it work with a proxy?